# Is every discrete, torsion and divisible group $\sigma-$compact?

Tags: topological-groups

Let $G$ be a discrete, torsion and divisible group. Is $G$, $\sigma-$compact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $G$ be a torsion divisible abelian group. Let $H$ be an uncountable direct sum of $G$ with itself. Endow $H$ with discrete topology. The result is divisible torsion group which is not sigma-compact.